# Sharepoint online Search result source should be folders inside a document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, search-scope, search-results-webpart

I have a library with 7 folders. I want to include the results of my search from 4 folders only not all of the library. I need the query syntax what we need to use  in search result web part as i don't see any documentation to work with folders for search query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the Ahmad Zia’s reply:

You need to enter the query `path:http://<server>/<site>/<libray>/<folder>` without “Forms”.

For example:

```
path:http://sp/sites/team/Doc1/f1

path:http://sp/sites/team/Doc1/2018
```

(“Doc1” is the library name, “f1” and “2018” are folder names)

[image]

Comment: Yes, this seems to be perfect solution. I have another question, do we have any ability to use folder ID instead of name as 1 user he changed the name of the folder and the results were gone.

Answer (score 0):

The query syntax for multiple paths is

```
(path:"http://site/library/Forms/Forms1/*" OR path:"http://site/library/Forms/Forms2/*")
```

This should search only in two folders Forms1 and Forms2 of library. You can extend this for 7 folders

Comment: I don't think that's the syntax. The above answer was what worked for me. Thanks for your response